# Time, Speed, Distance problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

[image: Question]

**My approach:-**

Let speed of Xavier be a, and speed of Yohanna be b

now time taken for Xavier and Yohanna to meet at point D would be same (on their return journey)

According to the language of question , I made the following 2 cases:-

[image: The 2 cases]

**Case 1:-** When D lies outside AB (Figure 1)

from the figure 2x=2y => x=y

Distance covered by Xavier till Point D = (2x+5x+4x), speed =a , therefore time =11x/a

Now,

Time taken by Yohanna till Point D = (5x+4x)/b = 9x/b

11x/a=9x/b

**a/b=11/9**  , I have an option given for this , but according to me there is another case too

**Case 2:-** when point D lies in between A and B (Figure 2)

here 4y=2x => y=x/2

Now doing the same thing (equating time till D for Xavier and Yohanna as done in case 1)

Time taken by Xavier till D = (7x+5x+x/2)/a = 25x/2a

Time taken by Yohanna till point D = (5x+5x+x/2)=21x/2a

25x/2a=21x/2b

**a/b=25/21**

Isn't this case valid too ? or its just that they gave only one of the 2 ratios in options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 2 can be excluded by the real world presumption that each of the two people are (**only**) returning to their respective starting points.  The wording of the problem is consistent with this assumption.

That is, the person who started at B, will stop when they reach B.

Therefore, if D is in between A and B, then the two people would never meet at D.

Comment: According to the wording in the problem doesnt it mean that they are just moving in that direction ? How can we infer that they stop at their respective starting points ?

Comment: @Fin27  "Once they reach point C they immediately turn back and run to their starting point".  As poorly written as this phrase is, it can only be interpreted in one *meaningful* way: **each of the two** turns back and runs to each of their **individual** starting points.